# Calling Named Template

Tags: xslt

I would like to process a **frame** element in my source xml file using XSLT 2.0 (Saxon 9.1.0.7).  If the **frame** element contains a **renderer** attribute I need to send this from the **frame** template to another named template, otherwise I would like to send a default **renderer** value to the named template.

So in the source xml file I could have the following, in which case I would like to send a default value to the named template as a parameter:

```
<frame id="menu_frame_1">
```

Or, if the **renderer** attribute is defined in the source xml doc, then I would like to send that instead of the default:

```
<frame id="menu_frame_1" renderer="KONtx.element.Container">
```

The problem I am having is I don't know how to conditionally choose either the default, or the defined attribute if it exists and pass it to the named template.  I tried  using a **xsl:choose** within a **call-template**, but this is not allowed.  Also, I would move the choose outside the **call-template**, and set a variable with either the default, or attribute value, but variables are immutable so i'm not sure how to handle that case either.  Below is the template for the **frame** element, and the named template I am trying to call.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<xsl:template match="frame">    
    <!-- Call new object start named template below -->
    <xsl:call-template name="newObjectStart">
        <xsl:with-param name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></xsl:with-param>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@renderer">
                <xsl:with-param name="renderer">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@renderer" />
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:with-param name="renderer">KONtx.element.Container</xsl:with-param> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:call-template>

    ...
</xsl:template>
```

---

```
<!-- New Object Start Named Template -->
<xsl:template name="newObjectStart">
    <xsl:param name="id" />
    <xsl:param name="renderer" />

    <xsl:text>var </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$id" />
    <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>    
    <xsl:text>new </xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$renderer" /> 
    <xsl:text>({</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `<xsl:choose>` inside the `<xsl:with-param>` instead of outside.

```
<xsl:template match="frame">
  <!-- Call new object start named template below -->
  <xsl:call-template name="newObjectStart">
    <xsl:with-param name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
    </xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="renderer">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@renderer">
          <xsl:value-of select="@renderer" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="'KONtx.element.Container'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>

  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and makes perfect sense. I'm trying to get my head wrapped around how to use xslt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@renderer">
           <xsl:call-template name="newObjectStart">
              <xsl:with-param name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="renderer"><xsl:value-of select="@renderer" /></xsl:with-param>
           </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:call-template name="newObjectStart">
              <xsl:with-param name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="renderer">KONtx.element.Container</xsl:with-param> 
           </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:call-template>

...
```